# Calculate the $\sup$

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

Let us $A=\{\frac{1}{|\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi|}, n\in\mathbb Z \}$, Calculate $\sup A$.

I am confuse, because $n\in\mathbb Z$ then for me i need to find the infimum of $|\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi|$ that it goes to $\infty$ implies that $\sup A= 0$ right?

I thought well? or i am wrong?

Thank you

Comment: The fact that it goes to (positive) infinity doesn't really tell you much about its infimum, does it?

Comment: sorry, i do not understand, can you explain more please

Comment: To find sup A you decided to look at the inf of the denominator, right? Noting that it goes to infinity, which you did correctly, tells you about its sup, not its inf. You've gotten your infs and sups mixed up.

Comment: Oh thank you @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC..i get it, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that
$$
    \frac{1}{\left| \frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi n \right|}
    = \frac{2}{\left| \pi + 4\pi n \right|}
    = \frac{2}{\pi} \cdot \frac{1}{\left|4n+1\right|}
$$
So if you can find the supremum of $\left\{\left|\frac{1}{4n+1}\right|\right\}$, you are finished.

Comment: Thank you @Matthew Leingang, for me $\frac{1}{4n+1}$ is decreasing so the bigger value is fill in $n=0$ so $\sup  \frac{1}{4n+1}=1$,

Answer (score 1):

The infimum is $\frac{\pi}{2}$ because $\lvert \frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi\rvert  \geq\frac{\pi}{2} $ and it is achieved for $n=0$, so $\sup A=\frac{2}{\pi}$ and $\inf A=0$

Comment: thank you so much, you confirm the above statement.